# Team section - bootstrap alignment issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm experiencing a layout issue with my website (done using bootstrap 3)
For some reason the pictures alignment is messy (see pictures below)
Any idea what is wrong?

What I'd like:

[image]

What I have:

[image]

```
            <section id="team">
              <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-4">
                <div class="team-member">
                  <div class="image" style="background-image:url(../images/male-employee.png)">
                  </div>
                  <p class="name">John Smith</p>
                  <p class="position">Fondateur
                    <br>Directeur Général</p>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-4">
                <div class="team-member">
                  <div class="image" style="background-image:url(../images/female-employee.png)">
                  </div>
                  <p class="name">John Smith</p>
                  <p class="position">Responsable diétéaires</p>
                </div>
              </div>


              <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-4">
                <div class="team-member">
                  <div class="image" style="background-image:url(../images/female-employee.png)">
                  </div>
                  <p class="name">John Smithr</p>
                  <p class="position">Responsable dfsf, maux</p>
                </div>
              </div>
             </div>
          <div class="row">

              <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-4">
                <div class="team-member">
                  <div class="image" style="background-image:url(../images/male-employee.png)">
                  </div>
                  <p class="name">John Smith</p>
                  <p class="position">Responsable stome</p>
                </div>
              </div>


              <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-4">
                <div class="team-member">
                  <div class="image" style="background-image:url(../images/female-employee.png)">
                  </div>
                  <p class="name">John Smith</p>
                  <p class="position">Responsable Facturation</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-4">
                <div class="team-member">
                  <div class="image" style="background-image:url(../images/male-employee.png)">
                  </div>
                  <p class="name">John Smith</p>
                  <p class="position">Technicien</p>
                </div>
              </div>
           </div>

<div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-4  col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="team-member">
                  <div class="image" style="background-image:url(../images/female-employee.png)">
                  </div>
                  <p class="name">John Smith</p>
                  <p class="position">Accueil Clients et Secrétariat</p>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-4">
                <div class="team-member">
                  <div class="image" style="background-image:url(../images/female-employee.png)">
                  </div>
                  <p class="name">John Smith</p>
                  <p class="position">Responsable administrative et assistante de Direction</p>
                </div>
              </div>
</div>            

            </section>
```

Comment: Here is a proper sandbox I created for this, you may want to add it to your question... ;) http://www.bootply.com/Rd0bcmxNDc

Comment: Maybe [CSS3's flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) is worth a look? AFAIK the grid is generally more used on the base layout (sidebars etc) of a site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After each 3th div you could add this line to fix your height issue:

`<div class="clearfix hidden-xs"></div>`

**Explanation:**

The issue was occured by having divs with different heights. Since in bootstrap all `col-*` classes are floated, it's required to have some kind of clearfixing in similar cases to avoid misalignment. In this particular case the clearfix should not be applied to extra small screens because in that case there are 6 cols in a row instead of 3, so this is why i have used the `hidden-xs` class.

Comment: (I'm not the OP, just following this question) Nice one! It only had to be added once and it solved the problem apparently :)... can you maybe provide some explanation?

Comment: I created a testcase for this in bootply, then I forked that applying your solution, here it is: http://www.bootply.com/wycdEx1k5j - use it if you like...

Comment: Thanks sc3w! It works great with col-sm-4 (it returns 3 pics per line as expected), but with col-xs-6 col-sm-4, when viewed on a xs screen, I have 2 pics on first row, 1 pic on the second row, then 2 pics again the 3rd, 1 pic on the 4th, etc. Is there a way to have 2 pics, 2 pics, 2 pics on xs screens? (I guess this is conflicting with your clear fix after the 3rd pic). Thanks

Comment: @Greg in that case add `<div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>` after each second col and keep using `<div class="clearfix hidden-xs"></div>` after each 3th.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add more `rows` in your divs. Right now the code isn't recognizing your columns in the code properly because it doesn't have anywhere to put them. I would edit your code for you but I'm on my phone.

Try putting a `row`before the first member and ending row after the last member of the row and so on. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. But since I use col-xs-6 col-sm-4 , where should I close the row After the 2nd member or the 3rd member? Thanks

Comment: @Greg after the 3rd one